# Datazen Dashboard Files Restore

Tags: business-intelligence, datazen-server

I am new to Datazen. I have two Datazen Severs for Dev and Production. I want to move the Datazen dashboards from Dev to Production.

Can you please let me know how to achieve this. I have checked the CP but didnt find any such option to restore the files.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for an easy Import/Export..the answer is NOT POSSIBLE.

You should be able to use DZ backup & restore Feature to transfer a COMPLETE Server. But this "resets" the targetserver to the state of sourceserver.

So far I didn't find any way to transfer selected content like KPI-,Dashboard-,Datasource-Definitions :(

**KPI- and Datasource Definitions**
you need to create them manually on server2 via "Control Panel".

**Published Dashboards**
As soon as your dashboard uses a external datasource (a datasource configured on DZ-Server) it's not possible anymore to publish to another HUB or to another Server. (BTW: You also can't spread datasources and dasboard accross HUBs)

**Exceptions:**
If you have a Dashboard without ANY external data you can transfer between Servers using the Publisher Client:
- Browse on Server1 the Dasboard1
- Select "Create from existing"
- Select "Publish" and publish to Server2 as Dashboard1

Comment: If you are using Excel source, you can publish it from Publisher App, one server to another. But if you are using any other data source (SQL, ODBC, etc) publishing to another server goes to disabled in the Publisher App.

Comment: So isn't there any solution for this issue?if not,then its a total waste of time because we have to create those dashboard and kpi again.!!