# DataZen Deployment methods

Tags: business-intelligence, datazen-server

One of my customers have a very strict policy of using DEV, Test, and Production environments. How does this work with Datazen? If I develop my dashboards/KPIs in the Dev Environment, how do I then "deploy" this to Test and Production?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately "staging" Content between Datazen Environments is not possible so far...see also [Datazen Dashboard Files Restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32178335/datazen-dashboard-files-restore/32485477#32485477)

Answer (score 0):

Datazen does not currently ship with the ability to release code through environments

The metadata files for Datazen are quite basic, therefore it is however possible to achieve the effect of moving dashboards and hub configuration between environments by using Powershell